# How to access only integer values(Roll Numbers only) from HTML table and store the values in JS array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <table border="10px solid ">
      <tr>
         <th>S.No</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Roll number</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>Hemanth</td>
         <td>Kumar</td>
         <td>3205020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>Manish</td>
         <td>Raj</td>
         <td>3205037</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>Dinesh</td>
         <td>Kanth</td>
         <td>3205015</td>
      </tr>
   </table><br>
</body>

</html>
```

I need only roll numbers to be stored in a javascript array.
I'm a beginner in learning Javascript so please help me to solve this.
And also suggest to me any tutorials website to learn JS and jQuery quickly.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is [literally off topic here](/help/on-topic), though. Remember to read that policy article, and then also read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) article, to make sure your question fits with what's expected when you post to SO. With that said: what have you tried so far? Because if you've not written _any_ code yet, SO is not the right place to ask for help: once you've done your research, and started writing code to do what you want to do, and you get stuck, and debugging/searching doesn't yield results, that's when posting to SO makes sense.

Comment: I tried, you can't say like that.
My code is not good so I removed it.

check my code here:
<button type="button" onclick="tabletoarray()">Click here</button>
   <script>
      var arr_1=[];
      function tabletoarray(){
         var valuess = document.getElementsByTagName("td").innerText=Number;
         arr_1.push(valuess);
         document.write(arr_1);  
      }
   </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope thats what you need:

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

var myArray = [];

/*
First we get all "tr" elements from the table,
then we need to turn the node list to an array using "Array.from",
then we use the "forEach" function to work with this new array
*/
Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName("tr")).forEach(function(element, index){
  /*
  Using this "if" the code will ignore the first "tr" that are the titles
  0 is recognized as "false" for boolean operation, so any number will get as "true"
  */
  if(index){
    console.log(element.children[0].innerHTML,
                element.children[1].innerHTML,
                element.children[2].innerHTML,
                element.children[3].innerHTML /* <-- this one is the roll number */);
                    
    myArray.push(element.children[3].innerHTML);
    /*
    if you need to store the HTML Element use: .push(element.children[3]);
    The innerHTML propertie returns a string with the HTML text that is inside of an element 
    */
  }
});

    console.log(myArray);
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <table border="10px solid ">
          <tr>
             <th>S.No</th>
             <th>First Name</th>
             <th>Last Name</th>
             <th>Roll number</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Hemanth</td>
             <td>Kumar</td>
             <td>3205020</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>Manish</td>
             <td>Raj</td>
             <td>3205037</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>Dinesh</td>
             <td>Kanth</td>
             <td>3205015</td>
          </tr>
       </table><br>
    </body>
```